# Unable to get current location

Tags: iphone, xcode4, titanium, titanium-mobile

I'm working on a Titanium app (currently targeted for iPhone deployment, but ultimately intended to be cross-platform) that requires me to identify several institution locations and display the distance to each from the phone's current location. When I try to determine my current location using Titanium's `Ti.Geolocation.getCurrentPosition()` API, all I get is this message: **Location Services Disabled**.

I'm testing in the iPhone simulator and I've read conflicting messages about whether location services work in the simulator with Xcode 4.x installed (I'm running 4.2) so I thought I'd ask a wider audience here:

1. *Should* I be able to identify my current position in the simulator using Xcode 4.2?
2. If so, what do I need to do to enable location services? I have yet to find anything that works to enable these services.

For whatever it may be worth, here's the relevant snippet of the code I'm trying to run:

```
// purpose is required for iPhone 3.2+
Ti.Geolocation.purpose = 'Determine the current distance to each Inova Health System location.';

Ti.Geolocation.getCurrentPosition( function( e ) {
    alert( e.coords );
});
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Xcode 4.2 the simulator location service worked again. So yes, you can even set the location. Debug -> Location and there should be a list.

But the message you got looks like the location service might be disabled for your app, go and check the settings app in the simulator and also check on a real device.

Comment: I think you're right that this is at the app/simulator level. Unfortunately, I don't have an actual device handy right now so I'm stuck with the simulator. Any idea where in the simulator settings I might find the location settings? I don't see anything that looks location-centric. Thanks again.

Comment: Its the first option in the settings app in my simulator, called `Location Services`

Comment: Weird. "General" is my first option. My simulator version is Version 5.0 (272). Do I need to upgrade? I assumed that upgrading XCode would also upgrade the simulator, but maybe not?

Comment: Thats the same as mine, are you using Xcode on an official mac, the location service have been know not to work on a hackinthos. Als make sure that the location service have been turned on in the debug menu.

Comment: I'm on a 13" MBA, so it's official and recent. In my simulator's `About` settings, I show the `Version` as `4.3.2 (8H7)`. I assume that's the iOS version, but that's a very uneducated assumption.

Comment: Try deploying it on the iPhone 5.0 simulator, the 4.3 does not support location.

Comment: Aha! That's what I'm after. How do I get the 5 simulator? Like I said, I sort of assumed it would be part of the Xcode download, but apparently now. Is the simulator a separate download?

Comment: If you have Xcode 4.2 then you have the 5.0 SDK and simulator, you switch version in the simulator `Hardware` -> `Version` or direct in Xcode via the droplist next to the play and stop button.